# Check if a file is uploaded in File field in a paragraph

Tags: drupal, twig

I have a paragraph in home page. I want to check if the admin has a file uploaded to the field of a paragraph or not.
i am checking like this

```
{% if not (node.field_video_mp4.isEmpty == true) and content.field_video_mp4 is defined %}

source src="{{ file_url(paragraph.field_video_mp4.entity.uri.value) }}" type="video/mp4"

{% endif %}
```

but if the video exists or not, this gets generated in the Html.
Please help. I have tried a various of ways.

Drupal 9 with twig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally i found the answer. this works for me!

```html
{% if content.field_video_mp4[0] is not empty %}
    <source src="{{ file_url(paragraph.field_video_mp4.entity.uri.value) }}" type="video/mp4">
{% endif %}
```